# Is it possible $n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)$ is a square?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Let $n,k$ two integers greater than $1$, is it possible that $n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)$ is a square $m^2$, with $m$ an integer ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this reducible via completing the square to Pell's equation in the case where $k=1$?

Comment: @Michael $n(n+1)$ is never a square for $n > 0$. Because $n$ and $n+1$ are relatively prime, the only way for $n(n+1)$ is a square is to that each of $n$ and $n+1$ is individually a perfect square. It is easy to see that this is impossible unless $n=0$.

Comment: (I'll record another argument for $k=1$. Hopefully someone can see a proof for general $k$. :)) The number $n(n+1)$ is strictly between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, and hence is not a perfect square.

Comment: I see.  According to Wikipedia:

<b>Pell's equation<b> is any Diophantine equation of the form
$$x^2-ny^2=1$$
where $n$ is a _nonsquare_ integer.

I missed the "nonsquare" part.

Comment: cant you just use bertrand postulate an the fact that the largest prime less than n+k divides the product?

Comment: ops my fact is wrong..sorry

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer is no, it can never be a square.  This problem was originally solved by Erdos in 1939.  The [paper can be found here](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-14/3/194).

Later, in 1975 Erdos and Selfridge improved the result and solved a longstanding conjecture which was first considered by Liouville in the 19th century, by showing that the product of two or more consecutive positive integers is never a perfect power.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eric.

Comment: Here's the link to Erdos 1975 paper: http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1975-46.pdf
Some other papers from http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html might be of interest too.

Comment: @Jason Can you explain your final comment? What convinced you that the problem is difficult for perfect squares too?

Comment: @JasonDeVito:  Correction!! I was completely wrong, you had a very good point.  The $l=2$ case is much, *much* easier and was solved 36 years early in 1939 by Erdos!

Comment: Thanks for the links, Martin and Eric.

Comment: Just a quick question regarding something in the beginning of the paper. Why must the $a$'s have only prime factors less than $k$? I couldn't follow the reasoning in the bracket.

Comment: @EuYu:  All that he is doing is writing $n+i=a_i x_i^2$, that is splitting each factor into its square part (the $x_i$) and its squarefree part (the $a_i$).  The next thing he says is that each $a_i$ must have all its factors less then $k$.  The reason is the product could not be a square if there was some prime greater than $k$ dividing $a_i$, because such a prime cannot occur anywhere else in the product.  (So we conclude primes larger than $k$ must appear to an even power)

Comment: @Eric Ah, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Srivatsan:  After my initial question, Eric responded saying something to the effect of "most of the work goes into the square case", so I responded with a thank you and bowed out.  I then saw that Eric deleted that comment, so I deleted mine.  Apparently there was more to the story (and also apparently "@Jason" doesn't work once I no longer have comments in the threads).  Sorry to cause confusion!